# Only 1 PhotoImage will display with tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to create a treeview which also has images for each row. Whenever I run this I only get one image to display. How do I fix this?

BTW: `row[0]` sends back a file path, not an image

```
def displayDB(admPag):
    admPag.destroy()

    DBPag = Tk()
    DBPag.title("listr.")
    DBPag.configure(bg="#31A1FF")

    DBTree = ttk.Treeview(DBPag)
    DBTree['columns'] = ("ID", "Title", "Genres")
    DBTree.heading("#0", text="Boxart", anchor=W)
    DBTree.heading("ID", text="ID", anchor=W)
    DBTree.heading("Title", text="Title", anchor=W)
    DBTree.heading("Genres", text="Genres", anchor=CENTER)
    s = ttk.Style()
    s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=190)

    con = sqlite3.connect("GameDB.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM GameDB")

    for row in cur:
        img = Image.open(str(row[3]))
        resize_img = img.resize((130, 190), Image.LANCZOS)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img)
        DBTree.insert(parent="", index="end", image=img, values=(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
        DBTree.image = img

    DBTree.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

[image: the problem in question]

I think this has something to do with the python garbage collection. Like, it just deletes the last image every time in loops so that's why I only get my final image in the database. I can't think of a way around this.

Answer (score 2):

You're only saving a reference to one image, and keep overwriting that reference. You need to keep a reference to all images. The easiest solution is to use a list. The following example shows one possible solution.

```
DBTree.images = []
for row in cur:
    img = Image.open(str(row[3]))
    resize_img = img.resize((130, 190), Image.LANCZOS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img)
    DBTree.insert(parent="", index="end", image=img, values=(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    DBTree.images.append(img)
```